# Testing methods which share variables

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a test :

```
@Test
testLogin {
   String returnValue = login(username, password)
}
```

Once this test completes I would to test the value of `returnValue` in a separate test. `returnValue` is also a method parameter for another method :

```
@Test
testVal {
   performTest(returnValue)
}
```

To achieve this I could declare returnValue as a global variable and then ensure the tests run in order using `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` but this seems like a non standard and unclean approach ?

Does this imply that the code which is being tested should be re-factored ?

What are the alternatives ?

Comment: Why don't you just call `login` again? The point of "unit tests" is to test code *in isolation*, as opposed to integration tests.

Comment: `testLogin` should do exactly that: test the `login` method. That would include the return value.

Comment: I second that. Unit tests should run in isolation.

Comment: This isn't what I would call "sharing variables". Unit tests are designed to allow you to test a single _unit_, as if it were a black box, whereby you pass in some parameters (if any) and observe the actual output compared to your expected output (a common convention is to `assert` that `expectedResult` is equal to (or some other variation of a comparison) the `actualResult`, and that goes in a single test. If you really have variables that need to be used by all tests, you can use a `static` `@BeforeClass` annotated method, which will run once, before any test case.

Comment: @Dave Newton I could call login again, this would require that the login isolated test be run before the test which also uses login - to ensure if login fails the correct test fails

Comment: If you require a pre-requisite operation be run before any given test, you can use `@Before` methods, which will be run before each test case. You want to be out of the business of depending on the order in which your tests are run.

Comment: @blue-sky ... It would be correct for both tests to fail. It's still "wrong", though; a method that *uses* login should stub out the call so you're not testing the `login` method. *Unit* tests.

Comment: @DaveNewton "a method that uses login should stub out the call" can you elaborate on this? stub out the call ? I assume you mean no login asserts used in test where login is not tested in isolation ?

Comment: @blue-sky No, it means you wouldn't call the real implementation of `login`, instead stubbing it out and defining precisely what to return in order to test the edge conditions of whatever calls `login`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such test

```
@Test
public void testLogin() {
   String returnValue = login(username, password)
}
```

doesn't have much value. The only thing it tests is that method `login` doesn't throw an exception and I am pretty sure that it is not what you want to test. Where are the assertions? The following implementation satisfies this test:

```
public String login(Object a, Object b) {
    return null;
}
```

Your test should look like this:

```
@Test
public void successfulLoginReturnsExpectedResponseCode() {
   String responseCode = login(username, password)

   assertThat(responseCode, is(equalTo("SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN")));
}
```

If the `login` method does nothing, the return value will be incorrect.

This example uses [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) for better diagnostics and readability. You can also use `assertEquals`.

Regarding your question about tests sharing variables, it is very important that your tests (no matter whether they are unit test, integration tests or acceptance tests) do not share anything and are independent. Otherwise you will run into problems such as failing test because the other test didn't run or the tests were run in different order. You should be able to run any subset of tests in any order.

You should also consider a better name of the test, so it describes what the code under test should be doing. For example `successfulLoginReturnsExpectedResponseCode()`.